# Watson Text to Speech blank

Tags: text-to-speech, ibm-watson

I've an simple example using the Watson Text to Speech but, even with the examples, the audio returned file is always blank.

My code:

```
$result = shell_exec("/usr/bin/curl -k -u 'xxxx':'xxxx' -X POST \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --header 'Accept: audio/wav' \
  --output 'test.wav'  \
  --data '{\"text\":\"hello world\", \"voice\":\"en-US_AllisonVoice\"}' \
  'https://stream.watsonplatform.net/text-to-speech/api/v1/synthesize/'");
print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because of the `--output 'test.wav'` flag: the audio file is being saved to `test.wav` rather than being passed to $result via stdout.